# Xilinx ISE Unity Launcher

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

I am trying to create a Unity launcher for Xilinx ISE 14.7 in `Ubuntu 14.04`. Here's what I have done so far:

1. I installed Xilinx ISE 14.7 to ~/username
2. Created a `run_ise.sh` script with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                         
   . $ISE_HOME/ISE_DS/settings64.sh 
   ise
   ```
3. Created an `ISE 14.7.desktop` entry in `~/.local/share/applications` with contents:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/home/user/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/data/images/pn-ise.png
   Name=ISE 14.7
   Exec=bash '/home/user/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/run_ise.sh'
   Comment=Runs Xilinx ISE 14.7
   ```

I have manually verified that runnnig the bash script runs ISE properly, but I am having issues with the Unity launcher. The Unity launcher doesn't load ISE. I thought it might be a permissions problem, so I have given both the desktop file and the run_ise.sh script the same permissions. I have tried them both with *root* and *user* as owner.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Are there any logs file I can dig into that could help me get to the bottom of the Unity issue? I've tried Googling around to find the log files for Unity, but I couldn't find anything that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for ISE 13.4. I have just changed 'Exec' parameter of the desktop file.

> Exec='/home/user/Xilinx/13.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/ise'

To be able to run ISE, we should set environment variables first running `source settings(32/64).sh` in the ISE_DS folder.

It seems to works fine.

Comment: I'll give that a try when I get back to my desktop. Out of the office for the holidays. Thanks!